# Google Analytics: How to track a session that visited two pages in the same section?

Tags: session, google-analytics

I'm trying to find in Google Analytics how to determine the number of sessions where a user visited more than one page within a section. For example:

User visits the following pages:

> /
>   /section-one/page-a/
>   /section-one/page-b/
>   /section-two/

This user session would count as more than one page in /section-one/.

User visits the following pages:

> /
>   /section-one/page-a/
>   /section-two/

This user session would not count as more than one page in /section-one/.

How is this done in Google Analytics? Preferably without adding custom events.

Comment: If I do understand well, the Content Drilldown report is what you are looking for? Check https://catbirdanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/google-analytics-content-drilldown-more-useful-than-it-may-appear/

Comment: Hernan, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I don't think so. The Content Drilldown report will tell me cumulatively the number of pageviews within the section, but I don't believe that it tells me the number of sessions comprised of multiple pages within that section.

Comment: I am not sure I got your question in the beginning. Now it sounds to me like something you can do with a Segment that you will define like "Sessions - Page Contains - /section-one/". That will show you the number of sessions that saw at least one page matching the condition, check: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en

Comment: I am reading over your question, and I think that it is definitely something to be done with segments, because they allow to create such kind of conditions. I never set a condition like the one you mention, but I will let you know if I find out the way to do it.

Comment: Let me know if you think this is what you are looking for, so that I can properly write an answer.

Comment: Hernan, Yes, I think the Sequences segment will do it. Thanks! Go ahead and write an answer and I will recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jay, I think that your best solution is to build a segment in order to properly know how many sessions did see a given number of pages within a section.

This solution will work with a page that has a path structure that allows it, as described in your example: /section-name/page.

So, the way to achieve this is to create a [Segment](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en) using a "Sequence" of conditions.

The sequence will make the segment match the conditions using the following logic: if session viewed page within /section/ and later viewed another page within /section/ that user saw at least two pages in that section.

So the sequence will be:

> 1. Include Sessions with Page contains /section-name/ is followed by
> 2. Include Sessions with Page contains /section-name/

Add as many times as the threshold you want to track.

[image: Segment screenshot]

The only flaw I see is that if the user saw two times the same page, it will be counted as matching the condition. I can't figure a flawless rule yet to overcome that issue. I have tried some, but I cannot say they are a definite solution. Anyways, as long as I can see, this kind of segment does a good job, even if there will always be some error margin.

Maybe someone else knows a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the above method suggested by Hernan shows incorrect data. As detailed by [Analytics Edge](https://help.analyticsedge.com/article/misunderstood-metrics-sessions-for-pages/), "Google tags the Session count only to the first page viewed".
This means that the above example segment will only show sessions where "/section/" is the first page in a session and will not count the sessions where this page comes is in second place or later.

Instead, one could try to instead measure unique pageviews (as these count each page only once per session), but this way of measuring may not help in all scenarios (like Jay's question).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Content-Group with all the pages of the section and then use the Unique Views metric.
It is explicitly explained in the last paragrah [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853563?hl=en).

> When you have a row identified as (not set), the value for that row is
> always 0. When Analytics calculates metrics for Content Groups, those
> calculations are based on the index number identified on the page or
> screen. When a page or screen does not include an index number, no
> calculation is made, and it is included in (not set).

Comment: It is also documented [here](https://www.noisetosignal.io/2015/08/google-analytics-content-groups-unique-views-vs-sessions/)